# When can a program be only debugged by dbx, not gdb?

Tags: gdb, dbx

Today I tried to debug a program on Solaris SPARC by gdb, and it does not work. I was asked to use dbx, then I managed to debug the program.

**My Question:**

```
1. When can a program be only debugged by dbx, not gdb?   
2. When do we need to use gdb, not dbx?   
3. Does it depend on the compiler that compiled the code?
```

Thank you!

Comment: which compiler you are using in Solaris SPARC?

Answer (score 2):

> I tried to debug a program on Solaris SPARC by gdb, and it does not work.

Your question is of very poor quality: "doesn't work" can mean great variety of things, and the answer of why it didn't work depends on details, which you didn't provide.

Generally, compilers on Solaris emit debug info in a standard [DWARF format](http://www.dwarfstd.org/) that debuggers (such as `gdb` and `dbx`) understand and interpret.

However, there are several versions of the format (current is version 4), and if your debugger is old but your compiler is new, then you are likely to have problems.

Other reasons you may have problems:

- you invoked GDB incorrectly
- there is a bug in GDB, and it doesn't handle some legal `DWARF4` info.
- there is a bug in Sun `CC`, and it emits incorrect `DWARF4` info, which `gdb` rejects, but which `dbx` accepts.
- older `cc` emitted `STABS` format, which `gdb` may no longer support. (This does *not* appear to be [the case](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2013-01/msg00024.html) though.)

Comment: I think the first sentence (Your question is of very poor quality: "doesn't work" can mean great variety of things, and the answer of why it didn't work depends on details.) here is, though correct not a valid part of this answer, I think you should move it into a comment instead. However this answer is otherwise extremely detailed and well written so +1

Comment: Thank you, but I am new to Unix, so I don't have much clue about what's happening. Sorry I did not provide many details, but your answer helps a lot. I will try to figure out why gdb fails.